# How should I travel from Khao Sok National Park to Ko Yao Noi in Thailand?

Tags: public-transport, thailand, national-parks

I understand there is a local bus from Khao Sok back to Phuket, then a ferry to Ko Yao Noi.

There also appears to be minibus running from Khao Sok to Krabit, and then a ferry.

Looking at map, it appears the more direct route would be southwards towards Thap Put, and then a ferry from there (somehow).

Does anyone know the quickest way to achieve this using either local public transport or minibus? (i.e. without resorting to car hire, charter boat, helicopter, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Khao_Sok_National_Park#Get_in), the bus to Phuket runs every hour, while the one to Krabi is only once a day (11am departure).  So on that front at least, there's a good chance the Phuket route is the way to go.  It's a 4 hour bus ride approximately, while the ride to Krabi takes 3.

For the ferry, you have again the [two options](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ko_Yao):

> Phuket (Bang Rong Pier): 09:30; 11:00; 12:30; 14:30; 16:00 and 17:00
>
> Phuket (Chianwanich Pier (near Ratsada Pier) - Only to Ko Yao Yai):
>   Every day: 8:30, 17:00 (speed boat) | Sundays-Thursdays: 10:30, 14:00
>   | Fridays: 10:00 | Saturdays: 6:00, 10:30, 14:00
>
> Krabi (Tha Len): 11:00 and 13:00

So again, the ferries are more frequent from Phuket than from Krabi (the same applies from the island back).

My recommendation in terms of flexibility, ease, and frequency - I wouldn't hesitate to take the Phuket route, unless you have a specific reason to see Krabi.

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding both Phuket and Krabi, there is a third option:

According to my Lonely Planet Thai Island Beaches, there is a ferry at 1pm from a place called 'Tha Dan' in 'Phang-Nga' to 'Ko Yao Noi'.

I can't find 'Tha Dan' on Google Maps, but according to the map in the book you go south on Highway 40 from 'Phang-Nga' and turn left onto Rte 4144 towards the sea before you hit 'Takua Thung'. 'Ah Phang Nga' National Park is right there too.

From 'Phang-Nga' to 'Tha Dan' is 8.5 km and you can take a 'Sŏrng·tăa·ou' or motorcycle taxi.

But this still leaves us with the problem to get from 'Khao Sok' to 'Phang-Nga'. On Google Maps there is a Route 415 from 'Phanom' near 'Khao Sok' to 'Thap Put' and on to 'Phang-Nga'. The book doesn't mention any transportation, but the bus to Krabi may use that road.

So even though there seems to be a third more direct ferry from 'Tha Dan', to get there seems more complicated and may take longer than going via Phuket or Krabi.